# Recursive Function Loop Through Character Array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, character-arrays

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to loop through a Character Array using a Recursive Function. I figured it would be easy since I would know the length of the array but then the prototype is give to me which I have to use:

`void display(char str[])`

I can't imagine how I'm supposed to loop through this recursively without knowing the length. Can anybody give me a nudge on this please?

Comment: You want to get array size?

Comment: Think about what property of C strings tells you when to stop, and can thus be used as your base case.

Comment: I wish educators would come up with better use cases for recursion. It's ill suited to scenarios where the "search space" reduces slowly (such as reducing the character count by one per recursion level.

Comment: @paxdiablo, maybe they trying to implement LISP? Perfectly reasoanble task in this case... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void display(char str[])
{
    if (*str) {
        putchar(*str);
        display(str+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugly though the concept is, this is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

C strings (assuming your character array is a C string) are assumed to be null terminated. So, you could, for instance, use a recursive function to compute the length and look for the null character for your base case to know you are done.

Comment: `char arraysArentAlwaysStrings[7]={'n','o',' ','n','u','l','l'};`

Comment: @AntonKovalenko, Then how are you supposed to use that function signature without a global variable of some sort, which seems ridiculous? After reading the question again, though, I see your point. Perhaps the wording "Character arrays when passed into functions without an accompanying length are assumed to be null-terminated." would be more clear :) Either way, you'd have to specify that explicitly in documentation.

Comment: _C strings_ are null-terminated, character arrays are _not_ (necessarily).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @abelenky and @Nathan, a character array is assumed to end with a "null" char (usually `'\0'`).
Here's an example on how to find the number of characters

```
 unsigned int strLen( const char[] str ) {
     unsigned int len = 0;
     while( str[len] ) {
         len++;
     }
     return len;
 }
```

Comment: this is not a recursive function!